# SQL Reporting Services: Grid View

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hi I have designed a query that returns a set of data such as:

```
============================================
    |  Name  |  Phone  |  Address  |
--------------------------------------------
     Bob       -         5 Street
     Mary      -         3 Drive
```

What I want to do in SQL Reporting Services is to display data in a grid fashion.
Such as

```
Item 1   Item 2   Item 3   Item 4
Item 5   Item 6   Item 7   Item 8
Item 9   Item 10  Item 11  Item 12
```

For the dataset I provide.  I want it to auto page break when needed, etc.  Is there anything built in that I can use?  Any recommendations on how to do this is greatly appreicated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reporting Services will auto page break once a page is full.

In terms of displaying data like that, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Think you're after 'horizontal tables'

[link text](http://blogs.msdn.com/chrishays/archive/2004/07/23/HorizontalTables.aspx)